# Execute an online script gracefully

Tags: scripting

#### Context

I've set up a site to post scripts to which I can then execute later using the following command:

```
curl -so /tmp/script http://scripts.programster.org/scripts/1?output=raw && . /tmp/script
```

*This example script outputs "hello world" to the terminal.*

As you can see, that's rather long and messy and risks overwriting a user's file if they just happen to have a file called `/tmp/script`. I used to just pipe to bash like so:

```
curl -s http://scripts.programster.org/scripts/1?output=raw | bash
```

However, I want the command to work with scripts written in other languages such as PHP (using `#!/usr/bin/php` at the top of the script), hence the change to the first command.

#### Question

Is there a way that I can execute an online script without having to save it to the local filesystem, whilst also not knowing what program to execute it in beforehand? Perhaps there is a way to treat a url like a file which would allow me to do something like:

```
. http://scripts.programster.org/scripts/1?output=raw
```

Comment: Hint: You can circumvent using a fixed name for temp files by using `mktemp`.

Comment: I would not use /tmp for especially this kind of use. It is not a good security practice. Given the sensitivity of some scripts, I would place them in a https site with authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside of security matters, I hope you do realise the risks of running external scripts, this can be done by combination of `wget` and `source` (dot) command

`. <(wget -q -O- http://scripts.programster.org/scripts/1?output=raw)`

That means sourcing the script text into current shell

`wget -O-` makes download ot STDOUT, `-q` makes it quiet (free from messages)

`<(any command)` is process substituion that allows interpret the output as a file

P.S. curl - equivalent for`wget -q -O-` is  `curl -s -o-`

**UPDATE**

The above examples will sitll  not make use of she-bang of the external script, but will run in the context of the calling shell. To make use of the she-bang line, one **have to** save the file, make executable, and only then run.

You can use `mktemp` which will guarantee unuque names, then you'll have take care of removing temporary files. This can be combined in a wrapper that would take the external url as  paramter

Here's a working sample code for that kind of wrapper

```
#/bin/bash
exturl=${1?"No external url specified"}
tmpexe=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm $tmpexe' EXIT
curl -s $exturl  -o $tmpexe
chmod 0755 $tmpexe
$tmpexe
```